# stack_array in C++ Core Guidelines

Tags: c++, c++11

The C++ Core Guidelines mention something called a [`stack_array`](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#Res-stack). Its usage looks like:

```
const int n = 7;
int m = 9;

void f()
{
    std::array<int, n> a1;
    stack_array<int> a2(m);  // A stack-allocated array.
                             // The number of elements are determined
                             // at construction and fixed thereafter.
    // ...
}
```

But how can such a class be implemented? How can we dynamically determine the stack size at run time?

Comment: Just look how the class is defined. What is the problem?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow I haven't been able to find any concrete implementation of it. See [this issue](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/issues/347).

Comment: It would allocate it on construction. But a better guess is that it hides a VLA, using whatever implementation compiler extensions use for that. So, a VLA w/o changing the language rules for plain arrays.

Comment: Well, there's always `alloca`, but don't quote me on that. So yes, pretty much a VLA.

Answer (score 7):

As far as I know, `stack_array` is a suggestion for a hypothetical class that can not be implemented using standard C++ (as of current standard). Its implementation requires (currently) non-standard compiler specific support, and I doubt such non-standard support even exists yet.

The closest you can get is a macro, that wraps a call to `alloca` (a non standard feature, which is supported by many compilers). See roalz's answer for a link to a concrete implementation. I'm not sure if that approach can achieve any safety that is not achievable by VLA (another non standard feature, which is supported by many compilers) - which is not to say that VLA are safe to use.

Comment: That's weird. The guidelines do seem to strongly suggest that this is a thing that exists, given that they are literally encouraging people to use it.

Comment: The guidelines are known to be futuristic or at least hopeful.

Answer (score 2):

The Microsoft GSL implementation is still interested in having an implementation of stack_array provided, as of November 2016: https://github.com/Microsoft/GSL/issues/348#issuecomment-260241339

See also https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/issues/347 and particularly https://github.com/Microsoft/GSL/issues/134 which talks about why it's not easy.